# $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C^{2}}$

Tags: soft-question

When we think of $\mathbb{C}$ we are really thinking of the set of complex numbers which geometrically could be visualized as a plane but what is $\mathbb{C}^2$ and can it be *visualized* ?

Comment: $\Bbb C^2$ is $4$-dimensional as a real vector space.  You can still visualize it but you have to learn to think as a sequence of slices.

Comment: You can conceptualize $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a "plane" where the axes are "lines" representing compressed versions of $\mathbb{C}$. Of course, since those "lines" are actually copies of $\mathbb{C}$, they are $2$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, so while a point of $\mathbb{C}^2$ can be represented as as an ordered pair of two elements of $\mathbb{C}$, it can also be represented as an ordered pair of two points of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence also as an element of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has four real dimensions so it's hard to visualize but you can think of it as a sequence of 3-dimensional slices.

But one has to be very careful not to confuse the geometry of $\Bbb C^2$ as $4$-dimensional real space and the algebra of $\Bbb C^2$ as a two-dimensional complex space.  For example a line $y=2x+3$ in $\Bbb C^2$ is geometrically a $2$-dimensional plane.  That might lead you to think that every plane in $\Bbb C^2$ is the graph of a line, but that's not the case.

Also, you can have two planes in four dimensions that intersect in a single point.  In fact two "lines" in $\Bbb C^2$ cannot intersect in more than one point even though two geometric planes in four dimensions can intersect in a (real) line.

Comment: +1. For the OP, another point in the geometry-vs.-algebra picture: the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are *infinite-dimensional* (in fact, uncountably-dimensional) over $\mathbb{Q}$.